# Could not access Remote Windows Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have a website where users can Impersonate/Authenticate themselves to a remote server, and control specific windows services. It **works fine** if I am running the project **locally**, but when I **publish** the project onto the **Web Server** having *IIS server* running, It gives an exception:

*Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer (computer name). This operation might require other privileges.*

**My Work:**

1. A class that impersonates(works good locally):

   ```
   public class ImpersonationUtil
   {
       public static bool Impersonate()
       {
           string logon = "ADMIN";
           string password = "PASS";
           string domain = "THEDOMAIN";
           IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
           IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
           WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

           if (LogonUser(logon, domain, password, 2, 0, ref token) != 0)
               if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                   impersonationContext = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate).Impersonate();

           return (impersonationContext != null);
       }

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
       public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUserName, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       public extern static int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);
   }
   ```
2. Code to connect with services:

   ```
       ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("serviceName", "machineAddress");
       var status = controller.Status;
   ```
3. Web.config stuff(To read and accept the impersonation on web server):

   `<system.webServer>`
       `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>`
   `</system.webServer>`

Any Help?

Comment: this looks like asp.net, not classic

Comment: yes @John I have corrected it... Any help according to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (LogonUser(logon, domain, password, 2, 0, ref token) != 0)
```

to

```
if (LogonUser(logon, domain, password, 9, 0, ref token) != 0)
```

Not tested, but I think It should connect now.